# Salesforce OpenCTI API for lightning could not be initialized

Tags: salesforce, lightning

I want to write a sample demo using OpenCTI API for Lightning Experience. The 
URL I mentioned in the CallCenter's Adapter URL refers to a page developed using JSPs and served from a third-party domain. So, based on the documentation below, I connect to the OpenCTI API using the script-Tag.

```html
<script src="https://c.<yourInstance>.visual.force.com/support/api/40.0/lightning/opencti_min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

N.B. Salesforce documentation: [Connect To OpenCTI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_connecting.htm)

The problem is, that at page load, the browser-console logs the following exception message:
"uncaught exception: Failed to initialize Open CTI. Ensure that it is loaded from the right frame with correct URL parameters".

As subsequent problem, all OpenCTI functions return with error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: It seemed that loading the OpenCTI API took too long, so that at the moment as I invoked an OpenCTI function, the API was not accessible yet.
So, I ensured to dynamically load the API using an AJAX get request. Once the API is loaded, I set a flag to true, and begin my initialization things.